# What determines AWS Redis' usable memory? (OOM issue)

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am using AWS Redis for a project and ran into an Out of Memory (OOM) issue. In investigating the issue, I discovered a couple parameters that affect the amount of usable memory, but the math doesn't seem to work out for my case. Am I missing any variables?

I'm using:

- 3 shards, 3 nodes per shard
- cache.t2.micro instance type
- `default.redis4.0.cluster.on` cache parameter group

The [ElastiCache website](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/pricing/) says cache.t2.micro has `0.555 GiB = 0.555 * 2^30 B = 595,926,712 B` memory.

`default.redis4.0.cluster.on` parameter group has `maxmemory = 581,959,680` (just under the instance memory) and `reserved-memory-percent = 25%`. `581,959,680 B * 0.75 = 436,469,760 B available`.

Now, looking at the BytesUsedForCache metric in CloudWatch when I ran out of memory, I see nodes around 457M, 437M, 397M, 393M bytes. It shouldn't be possible for a node to be above the 436M bytes calculated above!

What am I missing; Is there something else that determines how much memory is usable?

Comment: Out of interest, what happens when it runs out memory? Can you just not add more to cache of is the faillure more spectacular than that?

Comment: @matt freake I believe the specific error that I received was "lpush failed." I can't remember the exact wording, but it wasn't obvious that I was OOM. I'm guessing that it would have worked to add to a different key that wasn't hashed to the particular node that was OOM, but I can't verify.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading it somewhere but I can not find it right now. I believe BytesUsedForCache is a sum of RAM and SWAP used by Redis to store data/buffers.

As Elasticache's docs suggest that SWAP should not go higher than 300 MB.
I would suggest checking the SWAP metric at that time.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, 3 years later I don't think I have those metrics anymore :(